# grub not showing different kernel options

Tags: linux, boot, grub

I have done a sudo update-grub and it gives the following output -

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.0.0-rc1-xia
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.0.0-rc1-xia
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
```

On doing a dpkg --list | grep linux-image, following is the output -

```
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic                         3.13.0-24.46                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.0.0-rc1-xia                             05                                                  amd64        Linux kernel binary image for version 4.0.0-rc1-xia
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic                   3.13.0-24.46                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                                   3.13.0.24.28                                        amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

Even though the kerenl image is present, it simply boots the old linux image and doesn't show the list of kernels present. How can I get the options menu at the boot of the system.

**EDIT**
Here is my grub file -

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10

GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: What distribution (and version) are you using? (I see from the configuration file, that it may be Debian or debian-based. I am less familiar with those.)

Answer (score 2):

Possibly need to update the GRUB2 configuration:

```
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

*Note: The "make configuration" command and configuration file location may vary. For example, it could be `/boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg` or `/boot/efi/EFI/centos/grub.cfg`.*

The settings files that control what configuration is made, are:

- `/etc/grub.d` (individual, in-order)
- `/etc/default/grub` (general)

From `/etc/grub.d/README`:

> All executable files in this directory are processed in shell expansion order.
>
> ```
> 00_*: Reserved for 00_header.
> 10_*: Native boot entries.
> 20_*: Third party apps (e.g. memtest86+).
> ```
>
> The number namespace in-between is configurable by system installer and/or
> administrator.  For example, you can add an entry to boot another OS as
> 01_otheros, 11_otheros, etc, depending on the position you want it to occupy
> in the menu; and then adjust the default setting via /etc/default/grub.

Comment: Tried it, still can't get an option during boot

Answer (score 1):

## Update/Repair/Install Linux Grub using command

---

"**grub2-install /dev/sda**" or "**grub-install /dev/sda**"

where sda is your hard disk drive.
if it successfully completed the command then it's done else try to mount that OS directories by booting from external pen drive with same Linux OS.
and then try following command from link http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd.

Answer (score 0):

Following changes to the grub file helped (/etc/default/grub)

1. comment GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
2. comment GRUB_TERMINAL=console

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to live CD on any of Linux based system you can just run  `sudo fdisk -l` to know the naming of your disk and where you installed one of the Linux based system like Ubuntu or Kali
After that on my machine on live disk it is named `sdb`

```
mount /dev/sda3 /mnt
mount –bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount –bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
mount –bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount –bind /sys /mnt/sys
chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub
exit
umount /mnt/dev/pts
umount /mnt/dev
umount /mnt/proc
umount /mnt/sys
umount /mnt
```

replace `sda3` with the exact name where Linux is installed.

After this reboot and you will be able to boot in that OS, so log on and do the following:

```
apt-get install os-prober
os-prober
update-grub
```

If it is Windows everything will be repaired

Comment: Is that `sdb` a spelling mistake?